# Are there a compact $K$ and an open $O$ such that $K\subseteq B\subseteq O$ and $\mu (O\setminus K)<\varepsilon $?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-measures

I want to know if the following theorem is correct.

> Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a Hausdorff
> topological space $X$. Suppose that $\mu :\mathfrak{B}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a locally finite measure. If
> there's a collection $\{K_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of compacts sets such
> that $X=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{K}_n^{\color{red}\circ}$, then for all $B\in\mathfrak{B}$
> with $\mu (B)<\infty$ and $\varepsilon\in (0,\infty)$ there're a
> compact $K$ and an open $O$ such that $K\subseteq B\subseteq U$ and
> $\mu (O\setminus K)<\varepsilon $.

---

I will write my proof since it may contain mistakes.

We can use the Corollary 3.4 (which is in the page 74 of the "[Measure and Integration](https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1050&context=mathfrp)" written by John L. Menaldi) to conclude that there're a closed $C$ and an open $O$ such that $C\subseteq B\subseteq O$ and $\mu (O\setminus C)<\varepsilon $.

Define $\tilde K_n:=C\cap (\cup_{i=1}^nK_i)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\{\tilde K_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a collection of compact sets such that $\tilde K_n\nearrow C$ with implies that $O\setminus \tilde K_n\searrow O\setminus C\,\,\color{red}{(1) }$.

Since $C\subseteq B\subseteq O$, then $O=(O\setminus B)\sqcup B\subseteq (O\setminus C)\cup B$ which implies that $\mu (O)\leq \mu (O\setminus C)+\mu (B)<\infty$ since $\mu (O\setminus C)<\varepsilon $ and, by hypothesis, $\mu (B)<\infty$.

Therefore $\mu (O\setminus \tilde K_1)<\infty$. With this inequality and $(1)$ we can conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu _X(O\setminus \tilde K_n)=\mu _X(O\setminus C)<\varepsilon $ and, consequently, that there's $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu _X(O\setminus \tilde K_N)<\varepsilon $. We conclude the proof since $\tilde K_N$ is a compact satisfying $\tilde K_N\subseteq C\subseteq B\subseteq A$.

---

I think that the proof above contains an error since with the above theorem we can conclude that $\mu$ is inner regular.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @Moya The problem is that I don’t know where the error is in the proof above. I also revised the proof of the corollary cited above and I didn’t see any mistake in it.